# Is querying the model from the viewmodel anti-pattern?

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, viewmodel, modeling

I use Linq-to-SQL to create my models. I have a Movies table that lists all of the users' favorite movies.

In my VM, I'll have access to a current user. I want to call to my linq entity to get all the users favorite movies. Is it bad practice to have the actual linq query to the Movies table directly in a method in my VM?

```
Public Class MyVM
    Public Sub GetMovies()
        'some linq query to get the movies based on the user's id
    End Sub
    ...more stuff...
End Class
```

Or, should I have that method in my model  and only call a `GetAll(ByVal id as Integer)` function from the model or a repository?

I'm pretty new to patterns. I know patterns are more of a guide, but I'd like to follow it correctly before I make those determinations when the situation arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view model is there to represent your data, for example on a view (in ASP.NET MVC).

For example lets say you have a view that has to display user data.  You will return a User object by ID from a service or repository call (to a database).  You will then map this User object to the view model.  Then you would return this view model to the view and the view will use it to display the user's data to the client.

If I could then I could show you some C# code.  I don't have time to go look up the VB.NET equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You should neither write any logic for populating the data from database in Model nor in  ViewModel, if you want to follow good architecture.

You should use DataServiceAgent to load data. For more information on DataServiceAgent Visit the this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_mvvm_topic2.aspx).

Service Agent introduce one more layer on the top of the application to interact with database and web services.

Comment: I was asking if I should write linq to query my models, not the db.

Comment: @Yatrix: Yep you did, but he is right, in a way. He could have it phrased as recommendation, but... It's better to have the logic of loading separated, so that you can change the underlying `DataProvider` if you need to. You said it by yourself, you're new to pattern. Why not using them both, if they fit together? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your DataAccess Layer with Presentation Layer. So yes, it is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For me. ViewModel and Model are same. The Model layer it´s a mirror of you View... then Why use ViewModel rather than Model? it´s a just naming conflict